# How to use Spring State Machine on the dynamic events

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I would like to build a work flow where the state transitions are based on the contents of input events, which means the event can't be defined statically like `enum`. All input events have the same event type.

The most examples of Spring state machine I saw use `enum` or String as the event. I ran some tests like the following:

```
transitions.withExternal().source("s1").target("s2").action(ctx -> {
    // here, ctx.getEvent() returns null
})

transitions.withExternal().source("s1").target("s2").event("static_event").action(ctx -> {
    // here, ctx.getEvent() returns "static_event"
})
```

In my case, i need to retrieve the event passed in at runtime, then in `action` lambda expression, parse the event to get some keys which determine if the state should be changed into another. So I expect something like the following:

```
transitions.withExternal().source("s1").target("s2").action(ctx -> {
        // i expect ctx.getEvent() returns MyEvent(...)
})

stateMachine.sendEvent(new MyEvent(...));
```

So how can I use Spring state machine to model this kind of flow?

Comment: StateMachine by definition is deterministic - which means all events, states and possible transitions between the states are predefined. In your case it seems some input comes in (like external Event that can have random structure, but holds certain properties) that should control the SM flow - in this case you need to write a translation layer between the dynamic events and the predefined SM events. Example: MyEvent() -> properties based translator -> SmEnumEvent() -> stateMachine.sendEvent(new SmEnumEvent(...));